# count a specific element in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to make a script that takes a row form a sheet full with dates, convert it into an array and count a specific date.

I managed to do all except the "count a specific date" part.

the dates in the array looks like this:

```
Fri Jan 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)
```

The arry:

```
Fri Jan 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ),Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ),Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ),Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ),Mon Jan 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

The wanted Output: (for "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)"

```
3
```

Comment: Just write a simple loop that compares the array element and increments a counter. Or use `array.filter(d => d == specific_date).length`

Comment: @Barmar I think this should be tagged `arrays`? Should I make the edit?

Comment: Post an example of the array and the desired output of that array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = ["Fri Jan 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", "Mon Jan 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)"];

var dateToCount = "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)";

var count = array.reduce(function (a, d) {
    return d == dateToCount ? ++a : a;
}, 0);

console.log(count);
```

**Note:** If you could have lowercases or other form of dates and want to get those counted as well, then parse the dates like this:

```
var dateToCount = Date.parse("Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)");
var count = array.reduce(function (a, d) {
    return Date.parse(d) == dateToCount ? ++a : a;
}, 0);
```

Comment: the third line gives me a Syntax error in Google Scripts

Comment: @SteffenBauer It could be that your browser doesn't suppot **arrow functions**. I updated my answer.

Comment: @SteffenBauer That's not an error related to my answer. My code works. Run it in a browser not in an emulator like in the link you provided! It sais the syntax error is in the `console.log` not in my code above it.

Comment: i think somebody deleted the my "Google Apps Script" Tag for this post -.-

Comment: @SteffenBauer Just change the line `console. log(count)` to whatever does show `count`. `Logger.log("Count is: " + count)` and check your logs for example!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of strings like these:

```
var arr = ["Fri Jan 27 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", 
           "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", 
           "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", 
           "Wed Jan 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)", 
           "Mon Jan 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (MEZ)"];`
```

Use 2 strings of code;

```
var day = new Date(arr[0]);
day = day.getDay() + 1;
```

Just read docs of Date object:

Date object itself: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Date.getDay() method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Comment: @ppasler, thanx. Fixed